# php sql count from 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql, join

I need to get a count from a table, based on data from 2 other tables.

This is my tables structure:

```
table1 (id, name)
table2 (id, a, b, c)
table3 (id, blah)
```

Can i do it all in one statement? Something like this:

```
SELECT count(*) from table3 WHERE table2.x=table1.name
```

The hard part is the x column is the name of 'table1.name'. So i dont actually know what x is when im running the statement.

This makes me think i'd have to run a statement to find the name of x before i run this one.

Or... maybe some JOIN?

CURRENT CODE WHICH I USE:

```
if ($rs[firearm] != "") {
    $sql_result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM db_firearms WHERE name='$rs[firearm]'", $db);
    $rs2         = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result2);
    $sql_result3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items_firearms WHERE player='$id'", $db);
    $rs3         = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result3);
    if ($rs3[$rs2[shortname]] < 1) {
        mysql_query("UPDATE players SET firearm = '' WHERE id ='$id'");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, post the tables structure.

Comment: table1 (id, name) table2 (id, a, b, c) table3 (id, blah)

Comment: Yeah what he said. This is too esoteric to figure out without the table structures.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, sounds like joins will be necessary.

```
SELECT count(*) AS num_rows 
FROM table3 
LEFT JOIN table1.name ON table1.name = table3.name 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.x = table1.name
```

Comment: You'll have to figure out the column name `x` in your PHP, perhaps, before running the query then..